# Get the tag name of a checked RadioButton

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, radio-button

I have a group of RadioButtons, each of them has a Tag name.
I want to get it. If no RadioButton is selected then it is empty. I only complete part of them.

```
string sGender = 
    groupBox4.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(r => r.Checked)
        .FirstOrDefault().Tag.ToString();
```

**Updated**:

It might get exception if no botton is checked.

Comment: So what is your desired result? Do you want all `Tags` of the checked RadioButtons(joined by `,` for example) or just one? Do you get an exception?

Comment: I don't want to use if else statement to avoid exception because it is complex. I want to use one line code to finish all.

Comment: Why is using if..else complex? Its one of the simplest code constructs there is and anything else you might use is liekly to be worse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is the question? Is there an error here? What is it and where? You need to make sure that you specify your questions as clearly and accurately as possible.

At a guess though `.FirstOrDefault()` can return null so I suspect you are getting a null reference exception there. You need to check for that before you go on...

```
string sGender;
var radioButton = groupBox4.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                    .Where(r => r.Checked).FirstOrDefault();
if (radioButton == null)
{
    sGender = "";
}
else
{
    sGender = radioButton.Tag.ToString()
}
```

And since you have asked you can use a ternary operator to avoid the word if. This is still effectively an if statement in any practical sense. You can either use it to just replace the if statement i have given above or you can do a one liner if you were really desperate to... I really would go for the most readable though since the other options really won't add anything and will lose readability...

```
string sGender = groupBox4.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(r => r.Checked)?
    groupBox4.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(r => r.Checked)
        .First().Tag.ToString(): "";
```

Comment: I just wonder that can we use a line concise code rather than using if else statement?

Comment: The fundamental issue is that you want to get a property from an object but only if that object exists. You're going to need an if statement somewhere. You could hide it in a ternary operator if you want but that is just an if really. Why wouldn't you just use an if anyway?

Comment: Yes, can we use ternary here?

Comment: Of course you can but it is far more complicated code in terms of readability than the version I posted above. I'll edit it in with ternary just because you asked...

Comment: Okay. Please also keep the old version as well.

Comment: I am guessing the answer is same as the previous one.